# How can I layout a calendar with css flexbox and not have the content expand the boxes?

Tags: css, calendar, flexbox

I made a calendar using css flexbox and it all looks pretty until I add some content into the days, then it expands the box and throws the layout off.  Here is a pic of what the layout currently looks like.  Notice the day with the yellow tag in it and how it is expanded.  I want to hide any content that would otherwise make the day expand.

[image]

my css looks like this

```
.calendar {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.week {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
}
.day {
  flex:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All flex items must have the same `flex-basis`, i.e. `flex-basis:5em`.

Alternatively, you could use `display:grid`.

Comment: I changed the flex-basis to 5em for .day, but it didn't have any affect

Comment: Do you have `flex-grow:0;` also?